# Can SQL perform calculation on update?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Can SQL perform calculation on update? For instance, the stored product quantity was **5**, and after being sold, say **3** items, I want to update the quantity left in the `product tables`,

```
    $sql_update = "
    UPDATE store_products
    SET 
        product_quantity = ?
    WHERE store_products.product_id = ?
    ";

    $result = $connection->run_query($sql_update,array(
        3,
        $product->product_id
));
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't get the question. Aren't youl looking for a simple UPDATE? Each time you sell a proudct you ran the update decreasing the amount of items sold

Comment: @MostyMostacho he's talking about 2 different tables, `product` and `store_products` Look at his update statement.

Comment: The real question is: why do you keep the same information (product quantity) in two different tables?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - to achieve what you describe you need to implement an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

For details and samples see:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html
- http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-update.shtml

**EDIT - as per comment a sample:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER produpd AFTER UPDATE ON store_products
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE product SET quantity = quantity - NEW.product_quantity WHERE product_id = NEW.product_id;
  END;
```

This trigger needs to be created in your MySQL DB... when you execute the SQL code from your question MySQL invokes this trigger and update the `products` table.

Comment: thanks. just had a look at the links you suggested but I still don't know how to use `AFTER UPDATE`...

Comment: Deleted my answer. After reading carefully mysql documentation on updatable views, it clearly said that only columns in one of the tables from the view could be updatable at a time. Not useful on this scenario. Upvoting this answer.

Comment: do I need the word `END` if I am updating using php and MySQL?

Comment: please read the links I posted... the work `END` is part of the trigger definition which needs to be executed exactly once on the DB (NOT in your php code!)... and `produpd` is the name of the trigger the code above creates in the DB...